# v, an extension of a premeasure will always be so v(E) <=u(E)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image: theorem]

[image: proposition 1.12 referenced in theorem]

I don't understand the part of the proof that shows that v(E) is always less than or equal to u(E). It appears to me that they are arguing backwards but I don't know how to conclude v(E) ≤ u(E).

Comment: You can write $\mu(E)$ using `$\mu(E)$` and $\nu(E)$ using `$\nu(E)$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\nu$ extends $\mu_0$ from $\mathscr{A}$ to $\mathscr{M}$ and $A_i \in \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow \nu(A_i) = \mu_0(A_i)$.
Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_i)$. For all families $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$  of elements of $\mathscr{A}$ ***(i)***

$E \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \Rightarrow \nu(E) \leq \nu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(A_i)$ by the additivity of $\nu$ ***(ii)***

***(i), (ii)*** $\Rightarrow \nu(E) \leq  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_i)$. This again holds for all families $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$  of elements of $\mathscr{A}.$

I.e. $\nu(E)$ is a lower bound for $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_i)$ for these families ***(iii)***

As a lower bound it must be smaller or equal to the infimum:

***(iii)*** $\Rightarrow \nu(E) \leq inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_i) | E \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \wedge A_i \in \mathscr{A} \hspace{.2cm} \forall  i \geq 1\} = \mu^*(E) = \mu(E)$